# normal distribution hazard rate increasing function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, normal-distribution

How to show this function is increasing convex function:

Define 
$f(z)=\frac{T(z)}{g(z)}$, where

$T(z)=\phi(z)-\alpha \phi(\frac{z}{\alpha})+z(\Phi(z)-\Phi(\frac{z}{\alpha}))\,,$

$g(z)=\Phi(z)-\frac{1}{2}\Phi(\frac{z}{\alpha})-\int_{-\infty}^{z}\phi(x)\Phi(\sqrt{\frac{1-\alpha^2}{\alpha^2}}\,x)) dx$

and $\Phi(z)=\int_{-\infty}^z\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ is the CDF of standard normal distribution and $\phi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$ is the PDF of standard normal distribution and $0<\alpha<1$.

How can we show $f(z)$ is increasing and convex (numerical graph of the function is increasing and convex)? (maybe it suffices to show for $z<0$, $\frac{T'(z)}{T(z)}-\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$ is increasing and positive. Note that even $\log f(z)$ looks convex increasing).

Comment: Note $T(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{z}\Phi(x)-\Phi(\frac{x}{\alpha}) dx=\int_{-\infty}^{z}g(x)-g(-x) dx$.

Comment: Also note $g'(z)=\phi(z)(1-\Phi(\sqrt{\frac{1-\alpha^2}{\alpha^2}}\,z))-\frac{1}{2\alpha} \phi(\frac{z}{\alpha})$.

Comment: $g(z)=Pr(X_i<z,X_t> \frac{z}{\alpha})$ is a conditional probability where $X_i, X_t$ are positively correlated bivariate standard normal (both mean 0 and variance 1) distribution with correlation $\alpha$.

Comment: One can show that for $z<0$, there exists a $\tilde z<z$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\tilde z}g(x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^z g(-x)d x=\int_{-z}^\infty g(x) dx$. Then we can show $\frac{T(z)}{g(z)}=\int_{0}^{z-\tilde z}\frac{g(z-x)}{g(z)}$. We can show $\frac{g(z-x)}{g(z)}$ is convex positive increasing. So we are integrating a bunch of positive increasing convex functions. But the bound of integral also depends on $z$, which makes things complicated.

Comment: Define $\Phi_{\beta}(X,Y)=\int_{-\infty}^X\int_{Y}^{\infty}\phi_\beta(x,y)dy dx$ where $\phi_{\beta}(x,y)$ is PDF of a bivariate standard normal distribution with correlation $\beta$. Then for $z<0$, $\frac{T(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^z \Phi_1(x,\frac{x}{\alpha})}{\Phi_{\alpha}(z,\frac{z}{\alpha})}$

Comment: Why don't you compute $f'(z)$ and $f''(z)$ in a symbolic computation software like *Mathematica* or *Maple*. Then you can discuss on them. :)