# Can you use Laplace transform to show a function is convex?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

First, I should say I just know about Laplace transform through Wikipedia.

My question is,

Can you use Laplace transform to show a function is convex? If so, is there any link to an example?

I have a function $\frac{T(z)}{g(z)}$ that I want to show is convex. 
If it helps this is the specific question: [normal distribution hazard rate increasing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858461/normal-distribution-hazard-rate-increasing-function)

Comment: Cannot you apply the simple criterion $$f''(x)>0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f \text{ is convex}$$ ?

Comment: The function involves integration of probability functions and I was hoping laplace transform can take the problem into a different space and makes it simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose that $f:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ is convex and of slower than exponential growth, so that it has a Laplace transform. Then $f'_+$ (the right-hand derivative of $f$) is right-continuous and non-decreasing. As such $f'_+$ is  the "distribution function" of a measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$: $\mu((a,b]) =f'_+(b)-f'_+(a)$ for $0\le a<b$. Integrate by parts to see that
$$
\lambda^2 \hat f(\lambda)-\lambda f(0)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}\mu(dx)=\hat\mu(\lambda), \qquad\lambda>0,
$$
where the $\hat{}$ denotes Laplace transform. It is known that a function is the Laplace transform of a positive measure (like $\mu$) if and only if it is smooth and its derivatives (starting with the zeroth, which must be non-negative) alternate in sign. (Such a function is said to be completely monotone.) Thus it seems that for $f$ to be convex, the function $0<\lambda\mapsto \lambda^2\hat f(\lambda)-\lambda f(0)$ must be completely monotone.